# Will updating to newest Windows 10 ADMX files cause problems?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, group-policy

I am currently looking for best practices when it comes to managing group policy in a mixed OS environment. We currently have Windows 7, 8.1, 10 pre and post anniversary OS versions (1511, 1603, and 1703 respectively).

We are looking to update the Windows 10 ADMX files on our central store on the sysvol share of our domain controllers, but we are hesitant because we are worried that the newest Windows 10 ADMX files might over-write our existing and created polices, causing problems.

It is my understanding that once you deploy the newest Windows 10 ADMX files, it's not great for managing older Windows versions as well (though this could be a misunderstanding on my part, it could be that its no good for managing older Windows 10 installs only, and have very little to do with managing Windows 7, 8.1 machines).  (I could be wrong about this, if I am, please if possible explain why)

I know historically that Microsoft has maintained pretty strong backwards compatibility with GPO files and OS versions, however, I was pretty certain that the anniversary update is a different beast in that it may have introduced possible conflicts that we are worried about when updating to the newest Windows 10 ADMX files.

The best case scenario would be that we can just update to the newest Windows 10 ADMX files and nothing is changed (custom-made polices not being over-written) and we can carry on as normal, but we are trying to be as cautious as possible and would like to know the best practice for updating to the newest ADMX files without damaging our current setup.

Thanks for reading and for all the help!

Answer (score 3):

ADMX files are essentially just instructions for the GP GUI on how to present the options available. They aren't actually tied to the resulting GPO objects once configured.  So even if you outright deleted all of your ADMX templates, all of your existing policies would still function just fine.  It would just be hard to edit them and the GUI would show a bunch of "extra registry settings".

So understanding that, it means that if you update your ADMX templates, the worst that can happen is that Microsoft has removed a particular setting you used to use for some legacy machines and you won't be able to modify that setting anymore unless you revert to the old version of that template.